# Previous day in Postman request

Tags: postman

I have below code in postman's pre-request script --which gives me current date.  I rather want yesterday's date (current_timestamp - 1 day).

```
var current_timestamp = new Date();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("current_timestamp", current_timestamp.toISOString());
```

I searched doc & net but could not get the answer.  Can someone please help me with reference to date functions --to get my desired result.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) module in Postman to get a date in any format you need.

In the `Pre-Request Script`, add this to get what you need without using native JS:

```
    var moment = require('moment')

    pm.environment.set("current_timestamp", moment().toISOString())
    pm.environment.set("current_timestamp - 1 day", moment().subtract(1, 'day').toISOString())
```

This snippet will bring in the module and set the dates you require in the environment file.

For a non `moment` solution in plain JavaScript to just quickly go back 24hrs, you could do something like this:

```
var yesterday = (Date.now() - 86400000) // 24hrs in ms
pm.environment.set('yesterday', new Date(yesterday).toISOString())
```

Both solutions would give you the same outcome but I prefer to use moment as it's a built-in module that handles dates and times very well.